# Enviar 2 arrays mas variables mediante ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Buenas, sucede que tengo 2 arrays y 2 variables, las cuales necesito enviar via POST, hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveAsistencia.php",
            data: {'array':JSON.stringify(asistencia)},
            dataType: "html",
            error: function(){
            alert("error al hacer consulta");
            },
            success: function(data){ 

            $("#response").empty();
            $("#response").append(data);                                                             
            }
      }); 
   }
```

eso es para enviar un array tengo entendido, pero si quiero enviar 2 arrays mas variables, como debería hacerlo? gracias por las respuestas :)

**EDIT** :
Disculpen, me faltó agregar, como lo recibo en php? gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## AJAX

JavaScript Asíncrono y XML (**AJAX**) no es una tecnología por sí misma, es un término que describe un nuevo modo de utilizar conjuntamente varias tecnologías existentes. Esto incluye: HTML o XHTML, CSS, JavaScript, DOM, XML, XSLT, y el objeto XMLHttpRequest. Cuando estas tecnologías se combinan en un modelo AJAX, es posible lograr aplicaciones web capaces de actualizarse continuamente sin tener que volver a cargar la página completa. Esto crea aplicaciones más rápidas y con mejor respuesta a las acciones del usuario.

---

### ¿Qué es AJAX?

AJAX (JavaScript Asíncrono y XML) es un término nuevo para describir dos capacidades de los navegadores que han estado presentes por años, pero que habían sido ignoradas por muchos desarrolladores Web, hasta hace poco que surgieron aplicaciones como Gmail, Google suggest y Google Maps.

Las dos capacidades en cuestión son:

- La posibilidad de hacer peticiones al servidor sin tener que volver a cargar la página.
- La posibilidad de analizar y trabajar con documentos XML.

### javascript

```
 //arrays
 var array1 = ['1','2']
 var array2 = ['3','4']

 //variables
 var variable1 = "hola mundo1"
 var variable2 = "hola mundo2"


/*JSON a Enviar*/
 var datos = {
   'array1':array1,
   'array2':array2,
   'variable1':variable1,
   'variable2':variable2
 }

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveAsistencia.php",
        data: datos,
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(){
        alert("error al hacer consulta");
        },
        success: function(data){ 

        $("#response").empty();
        $("#response").append(data);                                                             
        }
   }); 
}
```

### PHP

```
 <?php
   echo $_GET["array1"]
 ?>
```

El data del success deberia mostrar el mismo array que pasaste como parametro espero te ayude saludos

Comment: interesante, lo voy a probar, gracias.

Comment: Prueba con este [tutorial](https://cybmeta.com/ajax-con-json-y-php-ejemplo-paso-a-paso) espero te ayude saludos

Comment: disculpa que te moleste, hago el echo a la variable y me lo muestra así 12341 , el array asumo que era así asistencia = [1,2,3,4,1], como lo puedo tener como array?, es que necesito los datos individuales.gracias.

Comment: quitale la función `JSON.stringify()` que cambia el `array` a `string` o eso intenta avísame a ver ya lo quite del ejemplo

Comment: eso era, muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente ayudarte amigo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo, agregandolos a la propiedad data del ajax.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveAsistencia.php",
            data: {'array':JSON.stringify(asistencia), 'array2':JSON.stringify(asistencia2), 'variable':valor1, 'variable2': valor2},
            dataType: "html",
            error: function(){
            alert("error al hacer consulta");
            },
            success: function(data){ 

            $("#response").empty();
            $("#response").append(data);                                                             
            }
      }); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar varios datos por `AJAX` solo completa la estructura `JSON` que ya tienes, así:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveAsistencia.php",
        data: {
         'array1' : JSON.stringify(asistencia),
         'array2' : JSON.stringify(asistencia),
         'variable1' : variable1,
         'variable2' : variable2
        },
        dataType: "html", 
        error: function(){
           alert("error al hacer consulta");
        },
        success: function(data){ 
           $("#response").empty();
           $("#response").append(data);                                                             
        }
  });
```

}

Recuerda definir el parametro `async` a la hora de realizar la petición para definir si hacerla `asincrona` o `sincrona`.

Comment: disculpa la ignorancia,pero para que es esa funcionalidad?

Comment: @alexigallegos cuando hace una petición puede definir si el `script` debe de esperar a que la petición se complete antes de continuar  (`sincrona`) o por el contrario puede continuar aun si la petición no se a completado (`asincrona`).

Comment: gracias por la explicación.

Answer (score 0):

Sería de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveAsistencia.php",
            data: {
                   array1:JSON.stringify(arreglo1),
                   array2:JSON.stringify(arreglo2),
                   variable1: "valor1",
                   variable2: "valor2"
            },
            dataType: "html",
            error: function(){
            alert("error al hacer consulta");
            },
            success: function(data){ 

            $("#response").empty();
            $("#response").append(data);                                                             
            }
      }); 
   }
```